# In MS Word, how to replace a range of colors (say, reddish) to a single color

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word

I have a scanned/OCRed document which is used every week, but not all the "reds" are the same, nor all the "blacks" true black. There is a range of red to pink and of black to gray. I would like to standardize the two colors to dark red and true black without having to go through every page (over 200, each with several parts in different shades of the two colors).

Is there a way to select text based on a range in the RGB attribute, say R>200, G<100, B<100?

In the absence of a simpler, more elegant way, I supposed I could just use nested loops, but that would iterate half a million times.

Comment: Without your specific code problem we can't help you here.  If you have some code and want recommendations for improvement then you should post your code and question on [Stack Overflow Code Review Board](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  I you're unsure of how to compose a word module that might solve your problem, then take a look at [Allen Wyatt's post on searching for Non-Black Text](https://word.tips.net/T001387_Searching_for_Non-Black_Text.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a Find/Replace for a range of colours in one pass. You'll have to code for every conceivable RGB combination you want to change. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    For R = 201 To 255
      For G = 0 To 99
        For B = 0 To 99
          .Font.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
          .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
        DoEvents
      Next
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With 539,055 iterations to do per your specs, though, don't expect a quick result.